# Exclude specific Category from Layered Navigation - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

we are using custom theme and Magento ver. 2.3.3 version

Exclude specific Category from Layered Navigation:

please help me to find solution....

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you are asking to exclude a particular category displayed in the filter from the image shown.
You need to override this file

```
vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/view/frontend/templates/layer/filter.phtml
```

in your theme

```
app/design/frontend/[VENDOR_THEME_NAME]/[THEME_NAME]/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/filter.phtml
```

Here you will get the filter items which will be rendered in layered navigation,  where you can check for your custom category name or ID for which you want to exclude it from the loop so it wont be displayed in layered navigation.

Answer (score 1):

This already answered here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/293019/80023

Basically, you remove your unwanted filters from `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList::getFilters`